# Jbpm 6.0 calling WebSerices

Tags: web-services, jbpm

I am testing Jbpm 6.0 (uses bpmn notation) using JBoss Developer Studio.

Which is the straigther way to invoke a webservice with an activity. Is posible to "load" the wsdl definition in the proyect in order to work with known data types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to implement a WorkItemHandler to calls your web-service stub. The other alternative is to use a Service Task, but IMO it will not cover all the cases and it only complicates things.

Comment: thanks for your response.

I created an independent project in order to make a jar with the WorkItemHandler and then I put the jar in  /opt/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib in order to deploy it.

It works but:

¿Is this the best procedure to deploy the WorkItemHandler?

Comment: Yes, that the recommended procedure. Remember that WorkItemHandlers are technical assets that doesn't change that often and updating those must be responsibility of a technical person.